# Why doesn't c++ recognize a string when trying to convert it into another type?

Tags: c++, casting

I have a fairly simple class that looks like this:

```
class Person {
    public:

        Person(string name): _name(name) {};

        void greet(const Person& person) const {
            cout << "Hello, " <<  person._name << "!" << endl;
        };

    private:
        string _name;
};
```

Note that the `greet` method takes a parameter of the `Person` type. When I pass it a `Person` object, it works as expected. Now let's pass it a `string` as a parameter in this way:

```
Person maher("maher");
maher.greet("sam");
```

When trying to run that code in QT (on a machine running ubuntu), it generates the following error:
`no matching function for call to ‘Person::greet(const char [4])’`

I was able to resolve this error by casting the string in this way: `maher.greet(string("sam"));`

My question is the following: Why can't c++ *'see'* that I'm passing a string to the `greet` method? Does it have anything to do with the fact that the `greet` method accepts a `Person` object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`maher` is a `const char[6]`, and `sam` is a `const char[4]`, and both decay to `const char *` implicitly, but none of them is actually a `std::string`.

In function calls, the C++ standard allows an implicit conversion to be performed if there's a non-`explicit` constructor of the target type that accepts the type of the actual value passed to the function.

This is what happens when you call the constructor: you pass a `const char[6]`, which automatically decays to a `const char *`; the target type is `std::string`, which has a constructor that accepts a `const char *`; such constructor is called, and the `Person` constructor correctly receives his `std::string` parameter.

In the second case, this is not happening: `Person` does not have a constructor that accepts a `const char *`, but only a constructor that accepts a `std::string`. To reach the desired `Person` type the compiler would have to first convert the `const char *` to `std::string`, and then call the `Person` constructor. This double conversion is not allowed, mainly because overloading resolution would become a complete mess (which already is) with lots of ambiguous cases.

If you want to allow `greet` to be called with a C-style string you should either:

- create a constructor for `Person` which accept a C-style string (`const char *`), so that it can be constructed directly from a `const char *`, without going through the prohibited extra conversion
- create another overload for `greet` to accept an `std::string`.

On the other hand, IMO the cleaner alternative is just leave it as it is; the caller will just have to write

```
maher.greet(std::string("sam"));
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered. I'll accept this answer because it has the most explanation to the origin of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't passing a `std::string`, you are passing a C-style string with type `const char*`. Add a constructor for that too:

```
Person(string name): _name(name) {};
Person(const char *name): _name(name) {};
```

Note that while `const char*` automatically can convert to `std::string`, in this case that would mean 2 conversions (`const char *` > `std::string` > `Person`), which is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

```
maher.greet("sam");
```

This requires two conversions:

- First, `const char[4]` to `std::string` so that `Person(string)` can be called.
- Then `std::string` to `Person` so that `greet(const Person&)` can be called.

But chain conversion is not allowed.

So you either provide a constructor `Person(const char*)`, or pass `std::string` to avoid first conversion (listed above):

- If you provide a constructor `Person(const char*)`, then `const char[4]` will directly  convert to `Person` which then will be passed to `greet()`.
- But if you pass `std::string` to greet(), then `std::string` will convert to `Person` using the existing constructor in your code, and then the person object will be passed to `greet()` eventually.

In both cases, there is only one conversion.

Or, simply write:

```
//convert const char[4] to std::string manually.
maher.greet(std::string("sam"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It absolutely does "see" that you're passing a string and that's the problem.  You don't have a method that accepts a string as input.

Comment: It would compile if a string was passed.

Comment: The method accepting a string is there all right. He's just not passing one, but a C-style string instead ... (Put more easily understandable: That depends on your your definition of the word «string», and std:: string probably wins that contest for a lot of us.)

Comment: I was referring to the greet() method.  The only version takes a Person&, not a "string."  And just to be sure, I tried to compile it and it fails as I expected with: error C2664: 'Person::greet' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [4]' to 'const Person &'

Answer (score 0):

*Does it have anything to do with fact that the greet method accepts a Person object?*
Yes,

You can pass a string to `greet()` method because there is a constructor in your `Person` class which constructs a `Person` object through the string that is passed to it.

Passing a `char[4]` requires the `char[4]` to a string object first ant then apply the above mentioned conversion. This chaining of conversions is not allowed and hence.

Answer (score -1):

You could override the method to accept a string.

```
void greet(const string name) const {
    cout << "Hello, " <<  name << "!" << endl;
};
```

Comment: Creating a `new` person and doing nothing with the pointer but passing it to a function is a memory leak. You must not do that in C++. What's more, it would not work, as `greet` takes a reference, not a pointer. You'd need `maher.greet(*(new Person("sam")))`. — What you _can_ do (safely, in fact) is `maher.greet(Person("sam"));`.

Comment: @Nornagest: if you don't want to get more downvotes for the memory leak you should either fix it or delete the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I fixed it. I wasn't sure if this was the correct way, since it takes leftroundabouts comment out of context.